# Excel file unreadable after adding a "SUMIF" function to a sheet with C# .NET

Tags: c#, excel, openxml-sdk

When I try to add a SUMIF formula to an Excel file that has data, Excel says the file has "unreadable content" and asks if it has to try to recover the contents of the file. If I then click "Yes", it removes said formula and opens the file.

When I try to copy-paste the same SUMIF formula that was generated in the Excel file manually, it works. When I try another formula (a simple "SUM" for instance) it works.

Does anyone have any idea what could be wrong?

I'm using the [OpenXML SDK from Microsoft](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=5124) to write to the Excel file. Again, this code works perfectly for some formulas (e.g. SUM), but not for SUMIF.

```
/// <summary>
/// Gets or set the cell formula
/// </summary>
public string Formula
    {
        get
        {
            return _cell.CellFormula.Text;
        }
        set
        {
            if(_cell.CellFormula == null) 
                _cell.CellFormula = new CellFormula(); 

            _cell.CellFormula.Text = value;
        } 
    }
```

Edit: After opening the Excel file and checking the xml files within, I found that the SUMIF function is saved in the exact same way as the SUM function ("=SUMIF(J3:J33;L34;N3:N33)" and "=SUM(N3:N33)" respectively, both without quotes), so there is no real difference in how the formula is written to the file.

Thanks in advance!

-- Spoiler: The solution is to use "," instead of ";" when working with formulas in your code.

Comment: are you sure you respected the `SUMIF` format? especially the number of arguments

Comment: Yes, because if I just copy paste the formula (when I'm debugging I can see the formula that is generated) in the Excel file manually, it works like a charm.

Comment: my opinion (for whatever that is worth) is that your `CellFormula.text` requires different formatting to insert properly, a place to start might be your sumif criteria.... are you using a range as the criteria, or a string with quotes ie (`">32"`).

Comment: If you want to see what is actually being outputted in the file, before opening it in Excel you can open the .xlsx file as a zip file and take a peek at the particular formula. It should be written out in one of the worksheet.xml's.

Comment: @Pynner: I'm using a range as criteria. What do you mean by "different formatting"? Would there be a difference between formatting a "SUM" function and a "SUMIF" function (apart from the obious differences in the number of arguments)?

Comment: @NickMartin: I've did what you asked and I find the same formula over there ("=SUMIF(J3:J33;L34;N3:N33)" without quotes) as I had in my code when debugging and if I just copy paste this formula in my sheet manually, again it works...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever I get unreadable content errors when working with the Open XML SDK, I will create a blank worksheet and add the piece that is causing the errors to that worksheet.  I will then use the [Open XML SDK 2.0 Productivity Tool](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=5124) to see what gets generated behind the scenes and use the code it produces to get rid of the unreadable content errors.

I did those steps and noticed the following were added when you add the `SUMIF` formula.  The first being you need to add the formula to the cell using the following code:

```
    // Creates an Cell instance and adds its children.
    public Cell GenerateCell()
    {
        Cell cell1 = new Cell(){ CellReference = "A1" };
        CellFormula cellFormula1 = new CellFormula();
        cellFormula1.Text = "SUMIF(J3:J33,L34,N3:N33)";
        CellValue cellValue1 = new CellValue();
        cellValue1.Text = "0";

        cell1.Append(cellFormula1);
        cell1.Append(cellValue1);
        return cell1;
    }
```

This will produce the following XML:

```
<x:c r="A1" xmlns:x="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main">
  <x:f>SUMIF(J3:J33,L34,N3:N33)</x:f>
  <x:v>0</x:v>
</x:c>
```

The text value is just the result of the summation, which is zero in my case since the range I defined were empty.

Next you need to make sure the `worksheet` contains a `sheetDimension` which is defined as:

> This element specifies the used range of the worksheet. It specifies
>   the row and column bounds of used cells in the worksheet. This is
>   optional and is not required. Used cells include cells with formulas,
>   text content, and cell formatting. When an entire column is formatted,
>   only the first cell in that column is considered used.

The code that code generated for me was:

```
 // Creates an SheetDimension instance and adds its children.
 public SheetDimension GenerateSheetDimension()
 {
    SheetDimension sheetDimension1 = new SheetDimension(){ Reference = "A1" };
    return sheetDimension1;
 }
```

The XML looks like:

```
<x:dimension ref="A1" xmlns:x="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main" />
```

Next you need to make sure the `worksheetPart` contains a `calcChainPart` which will have a `calcChain` element with a `calculationCell` child.

> This element represents a single cell, which shall contain a formula,
>   in the calc chain. Cells are calculated in the same order as the c
>   elements appear in the Calculation Chain part.

This just tells excel which sheet contains the formula and which cell it is applied to. Here is the code and XML for mine:

```
// Creates an CalculationCell instance and adds its children.
public CalculationCell GenerateCalculationCell()
{
   CalculationCell calculationCell1 = new CalculationCell(){ CellReference = "A1", SheetId = 1 };
   return calculationCell1;
}

<x:c r="A1" i="1" xmlns:x="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main" />
```

Finally, the `workbookPart` needs a `calculationProperties` element which defines the collection of properties the application uses to record calculation status and details. Calculation is the process of computing formulas and then displaying the results as values in the cells that contain the formulas.

```
// Creates an CalculationProperties instance and adds its children.
public CalculationProperties GenerateCalculationProperties()
{
   CalculationProperties calculationProperties1 = new CalculationProperties(){ CalculationId = (UInt32Value)125725U };
   return calculationProperties1;
}

<x:calcPr calcId="125725" xmlns:x="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main" />
```

As you can see, all of these various elements and parts are created for you behind the scenes when you add a formula to a cell when using Excel.  Unfortunately, you are responsible for adding the necessary elements when adding formulas using the Open XML SDK.  Most likely one of these elements are missing from your Excel document, which is why you are probably getting an unreadable content error when opening up your Excel document.

Comment: Thank you very much for your exhaustive reply, but if what you say is correct in my case; then it should give me the same error (and fail to execute the formula) if I create the same file (with a lot of data) and just change the formula from "SUMIF" to "SUM" (all other rows of data that I'm adding stay the same). Strangely enough, this does not happen, or am I missing something here? Also, my formula has to contain the "=", otherwise it doesn't work either.

Comment: Ok, I finally figured out what was going on. It's so very stupid once I saw it, but here goes: you need to use "," instead of ";" when building your formula in the code. I didn't know and I was using ";" as I would with any normal Excel formula and focussing on just about every other possible angle. I'm now officially embarrassed.